# Android: When Button is clicked it will focus and move to other editText [vice-versa]

Tags: java, android

PS: This is just an example, this is not my actual application.

I want to basically if the `buttonTwo` is clicked it will move to the other editText field, and when again press the `buttonTwo` it will move back to the editText field [vice versa over and over again].

Because `buttonOne` is basically going to generate "letters" and I don't want just to click the editText, I want "if the buttonTwo is clicked it will move to the other editText (vice-versa)"

code on my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String letter;
EditText txtNumber;
EditText txtMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMesssage);
    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block1);
    Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block2);

    txtNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMesssage);
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    /* if(txtNumber.requestFocus()) {
        txtNumber.setText("");
    } else if (buttonTwo.getId() == txtMessage.getId()){
        txtMessage.setNextFocusDownId(txtMessage.getId());
        txtMessage.setText("");
  } */

  switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.block1:          
        //buttonOnePressed = System.nanoTime(); // assign times 
          letter += "A";  
          break;
     case R.id.block2:
        if(v.getId()==R.id.block2){
            if(count%2==0){    //check if button clicked secong time
                txtNumber.setSelection(txtNumber.getText().length());  
                txtNumber.setText(letter);
             } 
             else
            {
                txtMessage.setSelection(txtMessage.getText().length()); ////when button clicked first time
                txtMessage.setText(letter);
            }
         }
          break;
        }
 }
}
```

on my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:hint="Enter Mobile Number" >

        <requestFocus>
        </requestFocus>
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Button one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"

        android:text="Button two" />

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtMesssage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:imeOptions="Done"
    android:hint="Enter Message" >

</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is not working as it should be, I am getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on my onClick()

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.block4)
          if (txtNumber.hasFocus()) {
             txtMessage.requestFocus();
        } else {
            txtNumber.requestFocus();
        }
}
```

in another function `example()`

```
     if ( // initiate data ) {
        if (txtNumber.hasFocus()){
            txtNumber.append(mLookupMap.get(mapKey));
     } else if (txtMessage.hasFocus()){
            txtMessage.append(mLookupMap.get(mapKey));
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this inside onClick method

```
if (view.getId() == R.id.block1) {
        // generate letters
        txtMessage.append("A");
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.block2) {
        if (txtNumber.hasFocus()) {
            txtMessage.requestFocus();
        } else {
            txtNumber.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello when I tried clicking the buttonOne, it will generate a letter, but it depends on what you've code. for e.g `txtMessage.setText(letter)` it will only generate in txtMessage..

Comment: @pjforum I have updated the answer, is this what you are trying to get.